# Whole CSS disappearing on Gmail

Tags: css, gmail, tailwind-css, nodemailer

I use Maizzle as an email template generator, I use API over the CLI because of localization that I need but generated template looks fine, works fine, I checked it on Thunderbird and it looks good, but on (I think) most popular email client CSS completely disappears, both inline styles and  tag styles. I tried rewriting my whole template but it doesn't change anything.

Rewriting my template, removing all `--tw` variables, disabling some options in maizzle config, enabling some things.

There is my config.production.js

```
/** @type {import('@maizzle/framework').Config} */
module.exports = {
  build: {
    templates: {
      destination: {
        path: '../src/mail/templates',
        extension: 'hbs',
      },
    },
  },
  inlineCSS: true,
  removeUnusedCSS: true,
  prettify: true,
  shorthandCSS: true,
  language: 'en',
};
```

Ofc I don't use any "not supported" style, I checked everything in gmail documentation about supported styles, I still think it's because of tailwind variables exported by default by maizzle e.g.

```
<div role="article" aria-roledescription="email" aria-label lang="en" style="box-sizing: border-box; border: 0 solid; --tw-border-spacing-x: 0; --tw-border-spacing-y: 0; --tw-translate-x: 0; --tw-translate-y: 0; --tw-rotate: 0; --tw-skew-x: 0; --tw-skew-y: 0; --tw-scale-x: 1; --tw-scale-y: 1; --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity; --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px; --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff; --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5); --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000; --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000; --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;">
```

OR

```
*,::before,::after {
    --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
    --tw-pan-x: ;
    --tw-pan-y: ;
}
```

Comment: I can't see anything in gmail documentation that says it supports CSS variables. Have you found a reference?

Comment: I found somewhere on the internet that it doesn't, but I don't know how to disable rendering tailwind variables in maizzle...

Comment: Okay, I set
`experimental: {
    optimizeUniversalDefaults: true,
}`
in my tailwind.config.js and now only 90% of styles disappear, I still think it's because of maizzle generates css varibales inside inline styles...